# C++ Using Enum with Static Method

Tags: c++, enums, static-methods

new to QT5 only have done a little C++.  Mostly C#.  anyway, trying to make an enum and use it in a static method in a class.  the class file does not see the enum (compliler errors are "unknown Type name ActionNames.".  tried a few things, moving enum out of the class, using Gui:: in front of ViewNames in cpp file  etc.  I'm sure this is a pretty easy thing - but how can I do this? thank you.

Gui.h

```
#ifndef GUI_H
#define GUI_H

#include <QObject>

class Gui
{
public:
    Gui();

    enum ViewNames
    {
    MAIN_VIEW,
    WORK_VIEW
    };

    enum ActionNames
    {
    BACK,
    HOME
    };
    static std::string GetViewStringFor(ViewNames view);
    static std::string GetActionStringFor(ActionNames view);
};

#endif // GUI_H
```

Gui.cpp

```
#ifndef GUI_H
#define GUI_H

#include <QObject>

#include "Gui.h"

class Gui
{
public:
    Gui();

    static std::string GetViewStringFor(ViewNames view)
    {
        return "";
    }
    static std::string GetActionStringFor(ActionNames view)
    {
        return "";
    }
};

#endif // GUI_H
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with Qt, you have only imported the QObject header but there is no QObject object

Comment: try changing `ActionNames` to `Gui::ActionNames`

Comment: You are defining the class twice.  in gui.cpp there shouldn't be a class definition at all.

Comment: Hold on.  The GUI_H #include guard is in both files so the class defined in gui.cpp is the ONLY class veing defined - nothing in the gui.h file is being included at all.  And the class in gui.cpp doesn't have the enum definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the class twice slightly differently: once in gui.cpp and once in gui.h

The difference in the two classes is that the enum definitions aren't declared in the class in gui.cpp.

Your gui.cpp file defines the GUI_H symbol and then includes gui.h which checks for the GUI_H symbol.  Because it exists nothing in gui.h is included.

So that means the class in gui.cpp is the one that is used and the one in gui.h is ignored, but the enums aren't declared in the class in gui.cpp so the compiler can't find them.

To fix it, change gui.cpp like this:

```
#include <QObject>
#include "Gui.h"

Gui::Gui()
{
}
static std::string Gui::GetViewStringFor(Gui::ViewNames view)
{
    return "";
}
static std::string Gui::GetActionStringFor(Gui::ActionNames view)
{
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

big oversight - the cpp file included class again... whoops... thanks everyone.

```
#include "Gui.h"

Gui::Gui()
{

}

static std::string GetViewStringFor(Gui::ViewNames view)
{
    return "";
}

static std::string GetActionStringFor(Gui::ActionNames view)
{
    return "";
}
```